# Foreign Key asp.net core with postgress

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, html.dropdownlistfor

I have this file upload form

```
@model FileUploadViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";

}
<h4>Start Uploading Files Here</h4>
<hr />
@if (ViewBag.Message != null)
{
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" style="margin-top:20px">
        @ViewBag.Message
    </div>
}
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="files" asp-action="UploadToFileSystem" method="post">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label asp-for="Name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" placeholder="name" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label asp-for="Author" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input asp-for="Author" class="form-control" placeholder="Author" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Author" class="text-danger"></span>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label asp-for="Genre" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"> </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select asp-for="Genre" class="custom-select mr-sm-2" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<Genres>()" ></select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label asp-for="Description" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" placeholder="Description" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row " >
        <label asp-for="PublishedOn" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="date" asp-for="PublishedOn" class="form-control" placeholder="Publishing Date" />
            <span asp-validation-for="PublishedOn" class="text-danger"></span>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label asp-for="Files" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="custom-file">
                <input asp-for="Files" multiple type="file" class="form-control custom-file-input" placeholder="file" />
                <label class="custom-file-label">Chose File...</label>
                <span asp-validation-for="Files" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" asp-action="UploadToFileSystem" asp-controller="Files">Upload</button>
</form>

@section Scripts{ 
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.custom-file-input').on("change", function () {
            var fileLabel = $(this).next('.custom-file-label');
            var files = $(this)[0].files;
            if (files.length > 1) {
                fileLabel.html(files.length + 'files selected');
            }
            else if (files.length == 1) {
                fileLabel.html(files[0].name);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
   
}
```

I want to make dropdown list with this table from postgresql database

[FileTypes table in pgadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yd8hl.png)

And i have this table for genres in database

[Genres table in pgadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdKHW.png)

So if i pick FileType with ID=1 in first dropdown,in the second dropdown i want to show only genres with with FileTypeID=1,I try to fill the genres table manualy but i have error(will be posted below).Any help for this way,or other way to filter genres dropdown depends on file type selected in first dropdown.[Error trying to fill rows in Genre table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXRek.png)

Answer (score 0):

Based on that error, you didn't create a foreign key but a unique index on that column in the Genre table. They prefix IX for index and FK for foreign keys by default I believe. Check your table relationships and check IX_genres_FileTypesID and I am pretty sure you will see the relationship isn't there.